# How to get my automated generated firebase node key?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

In my android project I want to update my status but I can't get the automated key which I want to update.

This is the code where I used in my project

```
String key = mGroupRef.child("users").push().getKey();
System.out.println("++key_____" +key);
```

Comment: To update a specific node, you'll likely have to first fire a query. How do you know what node you want to update?

Comment: sorry sir, i want to update status node,but i did't get the automated generated key

Comment: **What** status node do you want to update? I assume each child has a status, so how do you (as a human) know what status you want to update? Do you know its key? Do you know the address? Or do you want to change the status for all nodes that have `status=new`? The answer to those questions determines what code you need.

Comment: i mean push key , any way got my answer , thanks for ur valuable support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be helpful.

create a model `class`

```
public class Model {

public String uid;

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

}
```

save `status`

```
 ArrayList<Model>list=new ArrayList<Model>();
    Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Model model = new Model();
            Firebase firebase=new Firebase("your firebase url");
            String uid = firebase.child("order").push().getKey();
            model.setUid(uid);
            list.add(model);
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("order").child(uid).child("status").setValue(value);
            Log.i("uid", uid);

        }
    });
```

update `status`.

```
 update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("order").child(list.get(position).getUid()).child("status").setValue(updated value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answer has helped you. You need to know what node whose status is to be updated beforehand (as all node will have the status key) as @Frank van Puffelen has suggested.

Comment: i stored this uid  to a model class and i changed the status using this uid position